# did I match correctly both tenses past simple and present perfect

Tags: sequence-of-tenses

Can't finalize my order because I **have forgotten** my password, so I **tried** to recover it but **did not manage** to

will it be better to use forgot in that sentence even if at the time of writing I still have not recovered it OR use present perfect for try and manage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

English often has mixed tenses in one sentence. There's nothing wrong with having some present perfect and some past simple as in your example.